# Serverless Framework: How to add external NPM packages?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

My situation is that I am having a bit of trouble in adding external NPM packages to my Serverless Framework project (specific package is geopoint).

I went to the root folder of the Serverless project and ran `npm install geopoint --save`. package.json got updated with `dependencies": { "geopoint": "^1.0.1" }` and node_modules folder was created.

My folder structure looks like this:
root-project-folder
-functions
--geospatial
---handler.js
-node_modules
--geopoint

In my functions/geospatial/handler.js I declared the geopoint module with:

```
    var geopoint = require('geopoint');
    var geopoint = require('../../geopoint');
    var geopoint = require('../../../geopoint');
```

The lambda console returns an error of:

```
    {
      "errorMessage": "Cannot find module '../../geopoint'",
      "errorType": "Error",
      "stackTrace": []
    }
```

How can I properly add external NPM modules to a Serverless Framework project?

Comment: Why are you trying to resolve `../geopoint` and `../../geopoint` in the first place? Is it something specific to Serverless?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think what you are experiencing is the same as what I was experiencing recently.  I could install npm packages in my application root directory, but nothing would get deployed to lambda.

My understanding is that serverless deploys everything under each component directory (subdirectory under the application root).  In your case, under `functions`.

I could not find much in the serverless documentation around this, but what I did was define a `package.json` file under my `functions` folder and then run an npm install in that subdirectory.  Then after deploying to lambda, the `node_modules` under this directory got deployed too, meaning that my function code could require any of these npm modules.

So, your folder structure should now look like this:

```
root-project-folder
|-functions
|--package.json
|--node_modules
|---geopoint
|--geospatial
|---handler.js
|-package.json
|-node_modules
|--geopoint
```

The benefit here as well is that you can only deploy the npm dependencies that your functions need, without those that serverless needs to deploy your resources.

Hopefully that helps - once again, not sure this is best practise, just what I do because this isn't documented anywhere that I could find on the Serverless repository or in any example code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but I found another way. In the s-functions.json of the function I edited the line `"handler": "handler.handler"` to `"handler": "functions/geospatial/get_bounding_coordinates/handler.handler",` so that it will set the function root to the directory of the node modules.

Comment: Hey there.  Yep, thanks for sending that through.  I found that while your suggestion worked, the `sls dash deploy` took a lot longer because it tried to bundle up development dependencies from my root node_modules folder too.  While I could use `npm prune --prod` I think I'm going to keep a second node_modules like I use in my answer for the benefit of faster deployments and not having to prune dev dependencies each time I deploy.

Comment: You are correct that editing the value used for the handler attribute is the way to go. You should be able to structure your functions such that you can keep the node_modules very specific (as you want) to a given function(s). For example I have a package.json for my main project, and then two additional package.json files, one for each set of lambda functions.

Comment: Great call @Mikelax, anything to keep the size of each lambda function as small as possible is a good thing in my eyes.

Answer (score 8):

For me best solution was Serverless plugin: serverless-plugin-include-dependencies

[serverless-plugin-include-dependencies](https://github.com/dougmoscrop/serverless-plugin-include-dependencies)

Comment: Can confirm this. Worked flawlessly

Comment: Worked for me too!

Answer (score 6):

You can do the following:

```
# serverless.yml
custom:
  webpack:
    includeModules:
      packagePath: '../package.json' # relative path to custom package.json file.
```

[Reference document](https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack#node-modules--externals)

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks Man.

Answer (score 0):

If someone runs into this trouble and none of the answers above are helping, try this one(worked for me):

```
custom: 
  webpack:
    webpackIncludeModules: true
```